# Como traduzir a frase "minced oath" em português? (Palavras parecidas com palavrões, usadas pra não usar eles.)

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, tradução

Como dizer "minced oath" em Portuguese?

Na língua Inglesa "minced oath" quer dizer algo tipo "Oh fudge!" ou "Oh sugar!"; palavras usadas pra não usar palavrão (que normalmente tem um som parecido, ou começa com a mesma fonema).

Eu acho que "caraca" pode ser um exemplo disso na língua portuguesa.

Comment: Vc quer exemplos de palavras parecidas com palavrões ou a tradução de "minced oath"?

Comment: Some_Guy tens preferência por pt-PT ou pt-BR?

Comment: BR principalmente mas tenho interesse nos dois então por isso não botei nem um nem outro no descrição.

Answer (score 5):

Expressões como "caraca", são **"formas eufêmicas"** de palavrões e xingamentos.

> - [**eufêmica**](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/euf%C3%AAmica/) -  "que suavisa a frase, a maneira de falar."
> - [**eufemismo**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eufemismo) - "Eufemismo é uma figura de linguagem que emprega termos mais agradáveis para suavizar uma expressão.  Eufemismos também mostram serventia para substituir palavras consideradas de baixo calão ou impróprias de acordo com algum tabu, ou mesmo para omitir nomes de divindades. Alguns deles podem ser neologismos, isto é, palavras inventadas somente para a ocasião, em que se altera uma ou duas letras ou sílabas da palavra original."

Exemplos:

- "diacho" ao invés de "diabo"
- "filho da mãe" ao invés de "filho da puta"
- "caraca", "cacilda" ou "cacete" ao invés de "caralho"
- "ficar p da vida" ao invés de " ficar puto/a da vida"
- "vá pra ponte que partiu" ao invés de "vá pra puta que pariu"
- "como já dizia **F**ócrates, é **s**oda" ao invés de "é foda"
- "eu quero mais é que você **se ferre**" ao invés de "se foda"
- "pôôô, estragaste tudo" ao invés de "porra, estragaste tudo"

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta

Comment: Eu queria dizer que "caraca" seria um exemplo de um [minced oath] em português, mas talvez eu não comuniquei claramente.

Comment: "Caraca" é eufemismo por caralho não é ?

Comment: Also, "ponte que partiu" is hilarious, great bonus information hahaha

Comment: @Some_Guy - sim, "caraca" é isso mesmo

Comment: "Caramba" também é eufemismo por caralho?

Comment: @Some_Guy   Tinha entendido errado a presença da palavra "caraca" na pergunta.  Mas já consertei.

Comment: @JasonHaslam sim, "caralho" tem vários eufemismos: caraca, caramba, cacete (esse nem tanto, pois é meio agressivo também), catzo, cáspita (acho que esses 2 são mais regionais), canário (esse eu ouvi poucas vezes)...

Comment: @Hugo Onde é que dizem catzo e cáspita que eu nunca ouvi?  risos.

Comment: @Centaurus eu já ouvi algumas vezes aqui em São Paulo (tanto na capital quanto no interior), mas não são tão usados quanto caramba e caraca. Às vezes até eu falo "catzo"...

Comment: @hugo, caspita ao invés de cazzo (caralho) é por conta dos italianos (das novelas onde tem italianos), onde tiver concentração de italianos seja mais comum. http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/caspita_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/

Comment: @sumitani É mesmo, nunca tinha parado pra pensar. Em São Paulo tem muitos descendentes de italianos (inclusive o sotaque local tem muita influência destes), então nada mais natural que termos gírias originadas dos mesmos.

Comment: @Hugo Eu já ouvi "carai" também mas fiquei com a impressão que é um pouco mais pesado do que "caramba" ou "caraca". É mesmo?

Comment: @JasonHaslam Eu acho que sim. Pelo menos pra mim, dizer "carai" é equivalente a dizer "caralho"

Answer (score 3):

Um ***minced oath*** no português fica mais como um tipo de **[neologismo](https://www.priberam.com/dlpo/neologismo) eufemístico**. Significa a criação de uma palavra para suavizar (amenizar, mitigar) uma grosseria. Essas palavras não existiam no português e foram incorporadas popularmente com o tempo, podem ser criações ou derivar espanhol, italiano e afins.

Exemplos:

- puxa → puta
- diacho → diabo
- pô → porra
- buçanha → buceta
- vixe Maria → Virgem Maria

Do jeito que é utilizado no inglês, está mais para um [**trocadilho**](https://www.priberam.com/dlpo/trocadilho) (em inglês talvez seja *puns*). O trocadilho pode ser com qualquer coisa, fazemos um jogo de palavras, utilizando as que tem som parecido para evitar falar um palavrão, mas não me recordo de usar isso sem ser quando tentamos evitar falar palavrão perto de criança. Nesta tentativa saem coisas assim:

- pomba → porra
- filho da polícia (aqui o som sai *púlicia*) → filho da puta
- meleca → merda
- baralho → caralho
- joça → bosta